# Angular 4 - check if all page resources are fully loaded (make loader spins until all resources are fully loaded)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a loader for my angular app at work.

The most common method is passing the boolean parameter on subscribing http request, but my service's response is a series of image URLs because the page is full of images.

Thus the loader stopped when the URLs are retreived but due to a slow connection, the users are irritated because the image has not finished loading.

I have tried to use Javascript's load event to listen to when my resources have finished loading so I can stop the loader at that time, but it seems like I cannot manipulate the loader's value from the listener function.

Here's what I've tried:

```
//the TS component 
isLoading: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
this.isLoading = true;
this.checkIfLoaded();
}

checkIfLoaded() {
  window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");
    //here i should do something, either returning false or...
    //...manipulating the isLoading, but i can't access isLoading from here
  });
}


//the template
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
   <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</ng-container>
```

Environment: Angular 4.4
Any help are much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just make your component implement `AfterViewInit` and set `isLoading` to `false` in `ngAfterViewInit()`.

```
class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    // ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

There's no need to attach an additional event handler, angular covers that completely with its lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit still triggers too soon

Comment: ngAfterViewInit triggers after the component view is rendered but before all the libraries are loaded and the page is actually fully loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that you're not binding to the correct events.

If you want to know if the pictures have loaded, you need to create them and wait for them to load.

Start by getting your pictures, then create HTML elements to load them, then wait for all of them to have been loaded, and finally display them :

```
haveImagesLoaded: boolean[];

this.myService.getPictures().subscribe((urls: string[]) => {
  // no image has loaded, put them all to false
  this.haveImagesLoaded = urls.map(url => false);

  // Iterate over the images
  urls.forEach((url, index) => {
    // Create an HTML image
    let img = new Image();
    // Listen to its loading event
    img.onload = () => {
      // Image has loaded, save the information
      this.haveImagesLoaded[index] = true;
      // If all images have loaded, set your loader to false
      this.isLoading = !this.haveImagesLoaded.some(hasLoaded => !hasLoaded);
    };
  });
  // trigger the loading of the image
  img.src = url;
});
```

After that, you are free to display them with the method of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook and set isLoading to false in it.

TS

```
export class MyClass implements AfterViewInit {
  isLoading: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.isLoading = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<app-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></app-spinner>
```

Comment: this also considers the app-spinner in template so the spinner remains hidden